# RTC ds1307 module losing time

Tags: raspbian-jessie, rtc, system-clock

I am trying to get the [rtc i2c ds1307 module](http://www.ebay.de/itm/I2C-RTC-DS1307-AT24C32-Real-Time-Clock-Modul-F%C3%BCr-Arduino-AVR-ARM-PIC-SMD-B3/252609030217?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649) working under Raspbian Jessie.

I followed [these](https://learn.adafruit.com/adding-a-real-time-clock-to-raspberry-pi/set-rtc-time) guide to let the raspberry recognize the module and set it up.

Fortunately everything works great. I can access the module, read and write the time with `hwclock` etc.

But as soon as I disconnect my raspberry from power supply my RTC module looses time (reset to 2000-01-01 00:00:00). The 3V Battery is fully charged.

What  could be the reason for that behavior?

If I just reboot the pi without disconnecting it from power the RTC keeps the time correctly.

Comment: Did you check the battery pin connection to your RTC? The only annomaly I can see with your description is a disconnected battery to the module.

Comment: Actually this was the first thing I thought as well.. It appeared that the module itself was not working correctly. I used another with the same configuration and it worked! So maybe you should be careful if you buy cheap stuff on ebay!